# HTML5/CSS Footer issues with 100% height content

Tags: css, html, sticky-footer

This is my site currently:
[image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2z894pu.jpg]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="wrapper">
         <header>
         </header>
         <main>
            <section class="content">
               Test
            </section>
         </main>
         <footer>
         </footer>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #e4e4e4 !important;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff !important;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

header {
    height: 193px;
    line-height: 193px;
    background: #bc0000;
}

main {
    padding-bottom:137px;
}

.content {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #000;
}

footer {
    width:100%;
    height:137px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background: #bc0000;
}
```

I want that black content box to be 100% height.

I added this to CSS

```
#wrapper, main, .content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And site looks like this: [image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/i266ht.jpg]
How I can make black area to be from header to footer only without breaking site?

Thanks

Comment: background: #e4e4e4 !important; <--you should never need to use !important in this case

Comment: I will use bootstrap later and its required then.

Answer (score 1):

The height of your header is fixed to `193px` so you could use `calc()` function

```
#wrapper, main, .content {
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 193px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 193px);
    height: calc(100% - 193px);
}
```

I'm not taking into account other values that may affect this parameter (like borders, margins, etc.) so adjust this value so as it properly fits your design.

Use vendor prefixes where necessary. [Browser support for calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Answer (score 0):

Take `<header>` out of `<section>` (put it above) and your solution will work fine.

```
   <body>
      <header></header>
      <section id="wrapper">
         <main>
            <section class="content">
```

Comment: Thanks, after I did that, it gives overheight to content but it doesnt brake site: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2dglz5l.jpg
Any ideas?

Comment: Because of `main {
    padding-bottom:137px;
}`. You won't need that.

Comment: I still havent got it to work... I made some changes. http://jsfiddle.net/nDVcu/2/

I will add 193px background image to body so header is on purpose like that. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but it should not give scrollbar and I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: You could add `overflow: hidden` hidden to remove the scrollbar. I've updated the fiddle to show how. I'm not certain if this is what you wanted to do. http://jsfiddle.net/MattSmith/vDD3e/